# Reverse an integer, find the absolute difference, then reverse again

Tags: beginner, c, homework

For one of my university assignments, we were asked to take an `unsigned int`, reverse its digits, find the absolute difference between the original and reversed, then reverse that, and you receive the "Magic Number".

$$ R(\ \lvert R(A) - A\rvert\ )$$

where \$A\$ is a positive integer and \$R(n)\$ means reverse.

We were also asked to take multiple inputs at once and keep track of the largest absolute difference between all inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Reverse an unsigned integer
unsigned int reverseInteger(unsigned int input) {

    unsigned int output = 0;

    while (input != 0) { // Terminate when input is 0
        output = output * 10 + input % 10; // Can't use =* here, order of operations!
        input /= 10;
    }

    return output;
}

// Find the absolute differnece between a reversed number, then reverse the absolute difference
unsigned int generateMagicNumber(unsigned int input) {

    /* Find Absolute Difference */
    if (input < reverseInteger(input)) {
        input = reverseInteger(input); // If the result will be negative, reverse the number before finding the difference
        input -= reverseInteger(input);
    }
    else {
        input -= reverseInteger(input);
    }

    largestAbsoluteDifference(input);

    return reverseInteger(input); // Reverse absolute difference to find the magic number

}

// Find the largest of all values passed to this function
unsigned int largestAbsoluteDifference(unsigned int input) {

    static unsigned int keep = 0; // Must be static!

    return (input > keep) ? (keep = input) : keep; // If the input is greater than the current, store the input. Else, keep the current.

}

int main() {

    int inputs;
    printf("Enter number of inputs: ");
    scanf("%d", &inputs);
    printf("Enter space separated: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < inputs; i++) {
        unsigned int num;
        scanf("%u", &num);

        if (i == 0) { printf("\nOutput: "); } // Append label only on first iteration

        printf("%u ", generateMagicNumber(num)); // Generate and print the magic number
    }

    printf("\nLargest Absolute Difference: %u\n", largestAbsoluteDifference(0)); // Must pass 0 into largestAbsoluteDifference

}
```

**Example Input / Output**

> ```
> Enter number of inputs: 5
> Enter space separated: 23 512 454 94 100
>
> Output: 9 792 0 54 99
> Largest Absolute Difference: 297
> ```

**Notes / Concerns**

- The way I wrote the `largestAbsoluteDifference` seems slimy me to (having to pass 0 to get the result).
- I've got in the habit of calling functions inside a `printf` instead of storing the value in a variable and then printing the variable (see lines 56, 59). Is this okay?
- In `generateMagicNumber` I had to make sure finding the difference wouldn't result in a negative number (which you can't store in an `unsigned int`). Is my method the best way to find the absolute value like that?

Comment: Is `R` intended to be bijective? As implemented `reverseInteger(90)` yields `9`, which when reversed again yields `9`. If bijectivity is required, then you might have to operate on strings...

Comment: @MatthieuM. No. As it works is how it should. Good thing to point out, though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You write `unsigned int` enough times that it's probably worthwhile to `typedef` it, in case`unsigned int` turns out to be too small. (Keep in mind that it is only guaranteed to go up to 65535.)

```
typedef unsigned int number;
#define NUMBER_FMT "%u"
```

---

The `reverseInteger()` function is fine.  I'd rename it for clarity, then remove the superfluous comments.

```
/**
 * Reverse the digits of a number
 */
number reverseDigits(number input) {
    number output = 0;

    while (input != 0) {
        output = output * 10 + input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }

    return output;
}
```

---

The code in `generateMagicNumber()` was really hard to follow.  The call `reverseInteger(input)` appears *five* times in that function.  One codepath has four of those calls, and the other has three.  Not only is that suboptimal<sup>1</sup>, it's also confusing because the `input` refers to a different number each time even though they all look the same.  Please **avoid repurposing variables** like that.

```
/**
 * The reverse of the absolute difference between a number and its reverse
 */
number magic(number input) {
    number rev = reverseDigits(input);
    number absDiffWithReverse = (rev > input) ? rev - input : input - rev;
    return reverseDigits(absDiffWithReverse);
}
```

---

The ugly part of the problem is the requirement to keep track of the largest \$\lvert R(A) - A \rvert\$.  I see four unpalatable options:

1. As you have done, insert code inside `generateMagicNumber()` to capture the intermediate computational result.

   The disadvantages are that you are doing this as a side-effect, and using static (or global) state.  That kind of statefulness would become a maintenance headache on larger projects.  You also had to use a funny hack of calling `largestAbsoluteDifference(0)` to read out the maximum.
2. Instead of defining `generateMagicNumber()`, define `absDiffWithReverse()` to calculate \$\lvert R(A) - A \rvert\$.  Then, let `main()` be responsible for tracking the maximum of those.

   To get the magic numbers, `main()` would need to finish the job by reversing them.  It's a bit dissatisfying that, for a program whose primary purpose is to compute "magic numbers", there is no magic-number-computing function.
3. Define a function to compute both the magic number and the \$\lvert R(A) - A \rvert\$ intermediate result.

   Since C only allows one return value, you could either return a `struct` with two numbers or pass back one of the values as an out-parameter.  I find both techniques aesthetically unpleasing, especially since those two results can be trivially derived from each other.
4. <s>Define a function to compute the magic number.  To get the \$\lvert R(A) - A \rvert\$, reverse the magic number again.</s>

   As @MatthieuM has pointed out, reversing the digits twice could change the result, due to the possibility of trailing or leading zeroes.

I think I would prefer option 3:

```
number magic(number input, number *absDiffWithReverse) {
    number rev = reverseDigits(input);
    *absDiffWithReverse = (rev > input) ? rev - input : input - rev;
    return reverseDigits(*absDiffWithReverse);
}

number max(number a, number b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main() {
    int inputs;
    printf("Enter number of inputs: ");
    scanf("%d", &inputs);
    printf("Enter space separated: ");

    number maxDiffRev = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs; i++) {
        number n, nMagic, absDiffRev;
        scanf(NUMBER_FMT, &n);
        // Print label only on first iteration
        if (i == 0) { printf("\nOutput: "); }

        nMagic = magic(n, *absDiffRev);
        printf(NUMBER_FMT " ", nMagic);
        maxDiffRev = max(maxDiffRev, *absDiffRev);
    }

    printf("\nLargest Absolute Difference: " NUMBER_FMT "\n", maxDiffRev);
}
```

---

To address your specific concerns:

1. Yes, calling `largestAbsoluteDifference(0)` to read the maximum is slimy.  Ideally, static state should be avoided altogether.
2. Calling functions inside `printf()` calls is fine if they are pure functions with no side-effects.  It's not as good a practice if the function being called has side-effects.  I wouldn't worry about it in your case.  What I wrote above, with a variable assignment inside a `printf()` call, is probably far more controversial.
3. Your technique is arithmetically correct, but not recommended due to the `input` variable shifting its meaning.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not that performance really matters here.  What I'm pointing out is silliness more than a serious efficiency problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using static local variables like that is not a good idea for a few reasons. First there is no way to reset it for the next run. It's also not thread safe.

Instead pull that out into the main function:

```
unsigned int largest = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < inputs; i++) {
    unsigned int num;
    scanf("%u", &num);

    if (i == 0) { printf("\nOutput: "); } // Append label only on first iteration
    unsigned int magicNumber = generateMagicNumber(num)
    printf("%u ", magicNumber ); // Generate and print the magic number

    if(magicNumber > largest) largest = magicNumber;
}

printf("\nLargest Absolute Difference: %u\n", largest);
```

For generating the magic number you can call `reverseInteger` just once and then store the input:

```
unsigned int generateMagicNumber(unsigned int input) {

    unsigned int reverse = reverseInteger(input);
    /* Find Absolute Difference */
    if (input < reverse) {
        input = reverse - input;
    }
    else {
        input -= reverse;
    }

    return reverseInteger(input); // Reverse absolute difference to find the magic number

}
```

Comment: I think you oversimplified it: `largest` must consider the absolute difference (and not the magic number) - see the answer of @200_success

Comment: Think the correct term is reentrant, not threadsafe, if you add locks to a code that read*/writes to statics or global's it is thread safe, but not reeantrant. *read from constants is always safe of course.

Comment: @fhtuft non-reentrant in a non-recursive context generally means not thread safe